# Where does the acceleration that doesn't change our co-ordinate in space that ground applies comes from? (General Relativity)

Tags: general-relativity, forces, acceleration, geodesics

I saw this video of veritasium
https://youtu.be/NblR01hHK6U

I have this question...

[image]

if I am being accelerated by ground with 9.8 m/s2 then where this acceleration is actually coming from? I mean what I've understand is this one equation of General Relativity says that zero co-ordinate acceleration should be there for us just to stand still and not floating in a curved spacetime but there should be a force (i.e. Normal Force) accelerating the ground and hence us giving rise to an acceleration which is equal to the (spacetime curvature times our velocity through time squared part of the equation). If acceleration is actually a deviation from geodesic rather than a result to force then I didn't understand how are we actually deviating from geodesic? I mean sun wraps the space time and earth does follow the geodesic, doesn't it? that's why it revolves around the sun.. where is this zero co-ordinate acceleration coming from?

Comment: ScienceClic has some excellent videos on General Relativity. See the [playlist](https://www.youtube.com/@ScienceClicEN). You might start with this one. [0:00 / 0:06
A new way to visualize General Relativity ](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wrwgIjBUYVc)

Answer (score 1):

There are here 2 different concepts.

The first is to deal with non inertial coordinates. So in an uniformly accelerated frame, the 'true' acceleration (the covariant derivative of your picture) has a non-zero connection $\Gamma$. It is not curvature, but only shows that a body at rest in this frame ($a = 0$), is indeed accelerated (the acceleration of the frame). In this case there is no curvature, even when some connection is not zero.

The second is geodesic deviation, which is an indication of the presence of a gravitational field (and curvature). Because the space-time is approximately flat for a small place on the Earth, there is a connection numerically equal to that for an uniform $g$ accelerated frame. And that is what we call acceleration of gravity. But there are other non vanishing connections in this case, and the resulting tensor of curvature is not zero.

Answer (score 0):

When you're in an accelerated reference frame, you experience a force acted by the ground. In curved spacetime, since the spacetime is curved, geodesics aren't straight lines (in spaceTIME, not just in space). The analog to a free moving frame in flat spacetime are free-falling frames, since they seem to not being accelerated locally. Thus, when you're still at one point, you're not falling free. Indeed you experience the same effects (locally) as if you were accelerated upwards. The gravitational force is then just a fictious force, the force that deviates you from free-falling is the force the ground acts on you. The earth revolving around the sun is due to the effective potential by the angular momentum.

Think of it this way: in newtonian physics gravity pulls you down so you excerpt a force on the ground and by the newton's third law the ground excerpts a force on you. In GR, gravity is a fictious force, but the ground still pushes you upwards.

Comment: "and by the Newton's third law" NO. The force of ground on you can be different from your weight, and therefore can NEVER be the 3rd law pair that you are thinking it to be.